# Stop code from .dmp file?

Tags: bsod, minidumps

I have a .dmp file that a user emailed me and we are both running Windows 7.  What is the easiest way to translate/retrieve the Stop code from the file?

Comment: Which way(s) have you tried already? WinDBG? BluescreenView? One of several on-line analyzers?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a tool called Dumpchk.exe.  Although this was aimed primarily at the XP/Vista community, I have used it pn machines upto and including Win 7.  This might be worth taking a look at.

[Link to Dumpchk KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315271)

Answer (score 0):

Analyze it with Windbg from the Debugging tools. Microsoft explained it in this Video:

**Defrag Tools: #15 - WinDbg - Bugchecks (BSOD)**

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

To Get details about the bucheck, visit this website:

**Bug Check Code Reference**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx